# Counter the slowdown

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have a counter. After N time it increases by one. Which algorithm do I change the number N, to counter increased rapidly at first, and finally slowed down.

Thanks.

UPD: Source code on Java:

```
currentProcent = 0;
deltaSecond = 3000f / (float) bigProcNumber;    // 3000f - 3 second, is fixed
new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      try {
         while (currentProc != (int) bigProcNumber) {
            Thread.sleep((int) (deltaSecond));
            // UI Change
         }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}).start();
```

I need to change the deltatime, but it is necessary that the sum of all deltatimes was equal to 3000 milliseconds.

Comment: You can do something like "counter = counter + 100/counter" or something similar.

Comment: Your question is very vague. It's clear you are looking for a function of N that increases monotonically - it's no problem to create one. So you can specify properties you would like to have. it can be anything from `N_next = N+1` to more complicated `N_next = N! + N^2 + 1`

Answer (score 2):

If I interpret your question correctly you want to find a function which increases rapidly at first and more slowly later, something with a shape like this perhaps ?

[image]

I made the graphic using the `Log` function which would probably be suitable, but there are many others.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But I do not know how to implement it in my case, look, please on update with source.

Comment: I neither read nor write Java, but I'm sure someone else will help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uppercase 'N' is reserved. Don't use is as a variable name.
2. It sounds like you want to build a clock counter with a variable rate. 
      Mathematica has a couple of different ways to control clocks, and they have
      different characteristics. (look at `Pause[]`, the functions related to
      `CreateScheduledTask[]` or controlling update intervals in `Dynamic` e.g.) 
      Give us more hints of what you're trying to do. Example code is good.
3. Here's an example of a `Pause`-based timer.

   ```
   t = 0;
   Manipulate[
    t += dt;
    Pause[dt]; 
    Graphics[{Circle[], 
    Line[{{0., 0.}, {Cos[t/(2 Pi)], -Sin[t/(2 Pi)]}}]}]
    {{dt, 0.5}, 0.1, 1, 0.1, PopupMenu}
   ]
   ```
4. Be careful using timers around `Dynamic`. Here's an example using `Dynamic` to control
      the clock.

   ```
   Manipulate[
    DynamicModule[{t = 0},
     Graphics[{
      Circle[], 
      Line[{{0., 0.}, {Cos[#/(2 Pi)], -Sin[#/(2 Pi)]} &@
       Dynamic[t += dt, UpdateInterval -> dt]}]
     }]
    ]
   ,{{dt, 0.5}, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}
   ]
   ```

Comment: @Cfr - Thanks for the formatting. The editor here seems to be straightforward enough, but I simply can't get it do much useful on Safari. Firefox seems to work better.